# Android Screen Sharing

Tags: android, screen

Is it possible to share the screen from one android device to another, similar to how gotomeeting does it on a desktop. I understand that this may involve rooting the device.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. End-user questions belong on android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you talking programmatically or via some already-existing app?

Comment: I mean is it programmatically possible through the OS.

Comment: If you are asking about programming questions related to an API for screen sharing, this might be the right place.  Otherwise I suggest android.stackexchange or [su].  See e.g. [Is there a DLNA enabled media player for Android? - Android - Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/is-there-a-dlna-enabled-media-player-for-android)

Comment: Screen Share Android SDK: https://github.com/TeskaLabs/CatVision-io-SDK-Android